# Using cURL to download http post(ed) file

Tags: http, post, curl, embedded

I'm trying to have a webpage where you can upload a zip file and then the server (embedded linux) will download and save it. My HTML page has something like:

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="upload.cgi">
 <input type=file name=upload>
 <input type=submit name=press value="OK">
</form>
```

What I don't understand is how I can use cURL to download that file from the user's local computer to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will handle that for you.  The form you have specified instructs the browser to upload the file to the server using HTTP.